# Moving files from source folder to an archive folder which dont match with entered ids

Tags: c#

for my project perpose,
I want to move files from folder structure to 
an archive folder based on the files
whose names are **not matching** with the "filename" column values of a table.

Means i need to find all file names which are not present in the database then move these files into another folder.

Comment: Is there some code that you have written for this ?

Comment: What is the question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path); // get all files
foreach (var file in files.Where(f => !dbFiles.Contains(f)))
{
    File.Move(file, Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(file)));
}
```

`dbFiles` are files already stored in database. `destPath` is the path you want to move the files to.

Comment: quite performance-intensive as you check the db each and every time

Comment: There are no dbfiles. Just one table<"ID","FileName"> which contains the file names with ids

Comment: @Vogel612 No. Yes if `dbFiles` is an `IEnumerable` from a LINQ query from a LINQ-aware ORM. But I assumed it to be a simple `List<string>`.

Comment: @user2013 Obviousely, you need to first read the filenames from the database. If you don't know how, that's a different matter!

Comment: as you explained `dbFiles` to be stored in a Database and made no fetch in your code i assumed `dbFiles` to be an `IEnumerable`

Comment: Actually i m a newbie,So i need to get filenames using linq?

Comment: @user2013 Then that whould be a very different question! You need to read a book about it! There are many different ways to connect to a database in C#: [Bare ADO.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C), [EntityFramework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) and many others.

Comment: @ MD.Unicorn   ok i have converted perticular column to list using linq and passed to your answer THANKS,  Just wanna move file to another directory with the same folder structure as Source. and Create if not already exist

Answer (score 1):

you can do this task by following steps.

1. Get all files name from database as datatable format or list format.
2. Get FileInfo object to get all files from folder.
3. Compare this two object as datatable and FileInfo by foreach loop.
4. Get file name from fileInfo object which is not present in database.
5. Move this file into another folder.

I hope you can use this step and solve your problems.